# mySQL Relational Tables

Tags: mysql, relational-theory

Say I have 3 tables Products, Orders and Orders Product

```
Products Table

ID | StockNum | Description | Price
4  | 452SB    | Black       | 45.65
5  | 752SA    | Green       | 17.12


Orders Table

ID  | OrderNum | Total  |
14  | 12312    | 79.89  | 
15  | 12313    | 45.65  | 


Orders Product Table

ID  | OrderID  | Product  | Qty   | 
45  | 14       | 452SB    | 1     |
46  | 14       | 752SA    | 2     |
47  | 15       | 452SB    | 1     |
```

If product information changes (Price or Description) this would throw off all previous order information, whats the best solution for this?. Also does it make more sense to be storing the product ID instead of the StockNum?

** **Update** **
Does This Make More Sense?  Also everything marked with ID at the end is FK

```
Products Table

ID | StockNum | ProductDetailsID |
4  | 452SB    | 8                |
5  | 752SA    | 9                |

Products Details Table

ID | Description | Price
8  | Black       | 45.65
9  | Green       | 17.12


Orders Table

ID  | OrderNum | Total  |
14  | 12312    | 79.89  | 
15  | 12313    | 45.65  | 


Orders Product Table

ID  | OrderID  | Product  | Qty   | ProductDetailsID |  
45  | 14       | 452SB    | 1     | 8                |
46  | 14       | 752SA    | 2     | 9                |
47  | 15       | 452SB    | 1     | 8                |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the fields Price and Description to the Orders Product table and copy the values when you create the row. This allows you to read the values as they were by the time of the order execution

```
Orders Product Table

ID  | OrderID  | Product  | Qty   | Description | Price
45  | 14       | 452SB    | 1     | Black       | 45.65
46  | 14       | 752SA    | 2     | Green       | 17.12
47  | 15       | 452SB    | 1     | Black       | 45.65
```

And yes, using Keys is always preferable

**UPDATE**

About foreign keys. Display them like this

```
Products Table

ID | StockNum | ProductDetailsID |
4  | 452SB    | 8                |
5  | 752SA    | 9                |

Products Details Table

ProductDetailsID | Description | Price
8                | Black       | 45.65
9                | Green       | 17.12
```

Comment: JSantos, doesn't that seem very redundant to you by adding these to the Order Products table?

Comment: Redundant? Yes. Necessary? Probably. Redundancy is bad if it is unnecessary. There are other ways, all depends on the problem complexity and restrictions. In this case, this seams like a small classroom exercise. No need to add any complexity.

Comment: @Robert - it _is_ redundant, on purpose.  This is a textbook example of denormalization.

Comment: @dezso I understand that but what about my update?  If the product details change you just create a new row in Products Details and update the Product Table.  The Orders Products table won't be updated obviously.

Comment: @Robert that is a good solution

Comment: About foreign keys see my update

Answer (score 0):

*Using ID is a better solution.*

You need to employ a concept called **foreign key**. This is why relation databases are called relational -- because you use *foreign keys* to relate records in different tables. It does not just give you a simpler and more robust design, but also a *speed improvement*, once your tables got populated with thousands of records. Nice things to google: "*sql foreign key*", "*sql relations*".

Some helpful URLs:

[Article from MySQL Documentation about MySQL Foreign Key Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

[Article from w3school about SQL Foreign Keys](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Comment: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. well i looked through the exact article I referred to, and it seems to be alright. it's better though to refer to the MySQL documentation since the syntax is slightly different anyway, and it's more reliable.